# How do I debug a JBoss/Oracle JDBC over SSL connection string?

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, jdbc, jboss

I am trying to configure a JBoss Datasource, which connects to an Oracle DB via the Oracle thin client

JBoss version: 6.4.5.GA
Oracle version: 12.1.0.2.0
Thin client JDBC version: 11.2.0.3.0

The following un-encrypted datasource works with no problems

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/IDP_DS" pool-name="IDP_DS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST= (LOAD_BALANCE=on) (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=[HOSTNAME])(PORT=1521)) ) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME= [SERVICENAME]))))</connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>oracle</driver>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>[DB user]</user-name>
        <password>[DB password]</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>20000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>2</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>20</prepared-statement-cache-size>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

The following throws an SSL handshake failed exception (see below)

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/IDP_DS" pool-name="IDP_DS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST= (LOAD_BALANCE=on) (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=[HOSTNAME])(PORT=2484  )) ) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME= [SERVICE NAME]))))</connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>oracle</driver>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>[DB user]</user-name>
        <password>[DB password]</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>20000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>2</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>20</prepared-statement-cache-size>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

Exception thrown:

```
14:01:45,680 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component PreferencesBean for method public abstract java.util.Map com.adobe.idp.config.PreferencesSPI.getSystemRoot() throws com.adobe.idp.common.errors.exception.IDPException,com.adobe.idp.common.errors.exception.IDPSystemException: com.adobe.idp.common.errors.exception.IDPSystemExceptionorigin: com.adobe.idp.common.errors.exception.IDPException| [com.adobe.idp.storeprovider.database.DBDatasourceFactory] errorCode:8193 errorCodeHEX:0x2001 message:javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/IDP_DS
        at com.adobe.idp.config.PreferencesBean.getSystemRoot(PreferencesBean.java:93) [um.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52) 
        ...
```

and

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:467)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:323)
        ... 178 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.send(Packet.java:403)
        at oracle.net.ns.ConnectPacket.send(ConnectPacket.java:198)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:293)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
        ... 183 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_91]
        ... 191 more
```

The appropriate certificates have been added to the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts trust store but no luck

The DB server reports an "unknown error"

The DBA has used the connection string successfully (using SQL developer and SQL Plus), but has used Oracle Wallet for the certificate handling

I have tried connecting using Squirrel, but no luck. Is there a better way to debug this?

Comment: Did you import the full certificate chain into `cacerts`? You can enable [SSL/TLS debugging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) with JVM option `-Djavax.net.debug=all`. Depending on your JVM version, you might also need to tweak the TLS protocol list that's being used through another option, e.g.: `-Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174147/database-connectivity-over-tls1-2-using-jdbc-thin-and-jks/39224600#39224600]).