# Java 8 SSL Handshake failure

Tags: java, tls1.2

We are using SSL for our database (12c) traffic. While connecting to database using JDBC client (Java 1.8.0_65, ojdbc7), we are getting handshake failure. Our database server is using `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` cipher.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:752) ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666) ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566) ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.send(Packet.java:419) ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.ConnectPacket.send(ConnectPacket.java:241) ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:157) ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:264) ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452) ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496) ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
```

In order to analyse we have enabled ssl debug and found the below:

```
 *** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1491604703 bytes = { 8, 77, 210, 159, 243, 108, 135, 13, 187, 223, 121, 238, 236, 46, 76, 255, 76, 12, 130, 135, 233, 99, 154, 136, 70, 38, 132, 176 }
Session ID:  {223, 118, 94, 151, 92, 90, 47, 206, 76, 197, 24, 27, 241, 230, 236, 184, 87, 216, 9, 178, 99, 207, 38, 169, 193, 168, 99, 17, 211, 45, 239, 31}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 183
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 81
```

We could see is java client does not support the `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` cipher. So we have installed JDK8 Unlimited Strength Jars. Even after that also Java client does not support the `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` cipher.

My queries are:

1. Since the cipher is using a 256 bit algorithm, once I have provided the Unlimited Strength Jars, why Java client is still not supporting the above cipher.
2. As I could see from Oracle Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider), it says the above cipher is supported by default in `JDK 1.8`. Then also why the Java client is not showing that it is ignoring the above cipher.

I am not getting what am I missing here. Any guidance on this is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comment to use ojdbc1.8 resolved the issue. However, I got couple of more questions on this:

1. I can see, the handshake is now happening with TLSv1.2, previously it was happening with TLSv1. What I understood from [this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/jdk-8-will-use-tls-12-as-default) is JDK 1.8 by default supports TLSv1.2. Why it was not using the same previously.
2. Related to Cipher Suite, now with ojdbc8, additional ciphers are being passed which includes `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` cipher as well, which was previously not there with ojdbc7 jar. This [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) link says JDK 1.8 by default supports this cipher. But initially, it did not supported with ojdbc7. I did not understand this as well how making ojdbc8 makes the difference.

Comment: Any reason for using ojdbc7 (instead of ojdbc8) with java 1.8? Maybe there lies the problem ...

Comment: @Cyphrags There are no specific reason for using ojdbc7 jar. It was there in the server, so we are using it. I will change to ojdbc8.jar and try.

Comment: Are you sure the client is using Java 1.8? I would have expected a TLSv1.2 ClientHello from Java 1.8.

Comment: @EJP Yes, Its Java 1.8. If you notice the stack trace, it is 1.8.0_65. Moreover, in the server, the default java is 1.8, there are no other JDK installed in it.

Comment: You don't need 'unlimited strength'; AES-128 is not more than 128 and SHA256 is not encryption. But SHA256 suites do require TLSv1.2 and your client for some reason is offering only TLSv1.0 even though j8 should default to TLSv1.2 (as EJP said). Plus it already has a sessionid, which should only happen for resumption; are you sure this is the first relevant info in your trace? And read length=81 is much too big for an alert; are you sure there isn't anything after this but before the failure?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for your response. This issue got resolved once I used ojdbc8.jar. Now I can see the handshake is happening with TLSv1.2. Now I can see, client is sending SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 cipher as well and handshake is successful.

Comment: @Cyphrags Thanks, changing to ojdbc8.jar resolved the issue.

Comment: Apparently ojdbc7.jar does something to restrict the TLS protocols. If so, why is a mystery.

Comment: In your edit #2 is a result of #1; I don't know why ojdbc7 was using TLSv1.0, but given it was, the suite you want _cannot_ be used and must not be offered. All suites containing SHA256 or SHA384, and also all suites containing GCM or CCM (or ChaCha/Poly), are not allowed and cannot be used in TLSv1.0 because they require protocol features that are new in TLSv1.2 and do not exist in TLSv1.0. In fact earlier in your trace it should have said (a bit ambiguously) `Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error is due to Oracle [bug 19030178](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JJDBC/client-side-security.htm#JJDBC-GUID-89D2363B-DE5E-4FD6-8689-4A069302C076). This [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174147/database-connectivity-over-tls1-2-using-jdbc-thin-and-jks) explains the steps in details.

In `ojdbc7` jar we had applied the patch for `bug 19030178` and added the required `-D` parameters. With these changes, it worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the used library to ojdbc8 resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Even though it resolved the issue, I can not accept this as accepted answer as this does not provide any explanation on my questions and does not provide any detailed explanation on 'how', which I am looking for.

Comment: The problem is I can't answer 'why' - I'd need the source code for that and as stated in the OTN   license: "Further, You May Not: [...] cause or permit reverse engineering (unless required by law for interoperability), disassembly or decompilation of the Programs; and"

Comment: And (probably) ojdbc 7 used one or more variables or functions that most likely changed in Java 1.8

Comment: But nonetheless, I understand your decision and maybe someone can explain in detail what happened there :)

Answer (score 1):

The patched ojdbc7.jar for the bug 19030178 is located on [OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-cloud-3179120.html).  You can download this and also, using 12.2 driver will also work.

Also, refer to this post ["Database Connectivity over TLSv1.2 using JDBC thin and JKS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174147/database-connectivity-over-tls1-2-using-jdbc-thin-and-jks)